# How to call an executable from path?

Tags: linux

A very basic question here..

I have an executable `redis-server` at `/home/dave/redis/src`. Usually I `cd /home/dave/redis/src` then `./redis-server` to execute it.

How can I call `redis-server` in the path?  something like `/home/dave/redis/src./redis-server`

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it right. Except for the `.` (dot).

Instead of

```
/home/dave/redis/src./redis-server
```

Do

```
/home/dave/redis/src/redis-server
```

It is called an absolute path to the file, and it is simply the directories+file names, seperated by `/` (with a leading `/`, to make it absolute), so the `.` does not belong there.

Comment: thanks.. cannot believe my noobness

Answer (score 1):

```
/home/dave/redis/src/./redis-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dot in front of the first slash.

For example, if I want to open `netbeans` from the executable in `/home/jason/IDE/netbeans/bin/netbeans`,

I just put a dot in front of `/home/.../.../` and the executable starts.